# Spring quartz/cron jobs in a distributed environment

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a fleet of about 5 servers.  I want to run an identical Spring/Tomcat app on each machine.

I also need a particular task to be executed every ten minutes. It should only run on one of the machines.  I need some sort of election protocol or other similar solution.

Does Spring or Quartz have any sort of built-in distributed cron solution, or do I need to implement something myself?

Answer (score 2):

Hazelcast has a distributed executor framework which you can use to run jobs using the JDK Executor framework (which, by the way, is possibly more testable than horrid Quartz... maybe). It has a number of modes of operation, including having it pick a single node "at random" to execute your job on.

See [the documentation](http://www.hazelcast.com/documentation.jsp#DistributedExecution) for more details